# /etc/hosts changes ignored

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, vagrant, hosts

I want to add entries to my hosts file so I can access some local vagrant VMs for development.

I have a near-new install of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. There is a `/etc/hosts` file but changes I make to it are being ignored.

It looks like this:

```
1 127.0.0.1   localhost
2 127.0.1.1   q
3 
4 # The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
5 ::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
6 fe00::0 ip6-localnet
7 ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
8 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
9 ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
10 
11 # My custom section
12 127.0.0.1:4567   local.devel <-- being ignored
```

I have tried adding other entries but nothing is being read.

I have checked `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and it appears to have `files` as the first entry. eg:

```
  12 hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
  13 networks:       files
  14 
  15 protocols:      db files
  16 services:       db files
  17 ethers:         db files
  18 rpc:            db files
```

Which I think is correct. `dnsmasq` is installed but restarting the network manager also does not help.

Someone, please help I have been googling solutions for hours and nothing is working...

Comment: `/etc/hosts` can't specify ports (`:4567`), and should have unique IP addresses - not multiple `127.0.0.1` lines. `127.0.0.1 localhost q`

Comment: Ah. Thank you. It was the ports. The multiple lines seem to work fine though.